# Add space before image, javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to put some space to the left of the radio-play.gif button. What can add to this code to achieve that?

Thanks!

```
// Last (only one on Mac) row has the VCR buttons.
//
s += '<td>';
s += '<img border="0" src="/images/dot.gif" width="81" height="' + gPreBtnVertSpace + '"><br>';
s += '<img alt="PLAY" src="' + imageDir + 'radio-play.gif" width="72" border="0" padding="5" height="61" style="cursor:pointer; cursor:hand" onclick="HandleAction(\'playnow\')">';

if (player != 'MP3')
    s += '<img alt="STOP" src="' + imageDir + 'radio-stop.gif" width="72" border="0" height="61" style="cursor:pointer; cursor:hand" onclick="HandleAction(\'stop\')">';

s += '</td></tr>';

document.write(s);

// removing mute button
var myEl = document.getElementsByName("mute");
var elP = myEl[0].parentNode.parentNode;
elP.removeChild(myEl[0].parentNode);
```

Comment: `document.write()` is poor form (as is plain text manipulation of the DOM in general). Plus am I looking at a JavaScript generated HTML table for page layout?! It is 2012, CSS can do that so much faster, cleaner, easier, saner... better.

Answer (score 2):

Either set a margin to the `img` tag (it needs to be `display:inline-block;` for this) or add
a `&nbsp;` (No breaking space).

Probably the margin would be my preferred way, e.g.

```
img{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:5px;
}
```

or

```
s += '&nbsp;<img alt="PLAY" ...
```

Btw.: The correct way would be, to create the `<td>` and `<img>` elements via `document.createElement` and then attach them to the dom. (Or use jquery, it's a bit simpler there)

Answer (score 1):

You can literally put a space character infront of it. I would do it using CSS. Give the image a class `class="whatever"` and then in CSS:

```
.whatever {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Since you're doing it inline already, you could just add the margin in the inline css.

Comment: needs to be a block element to apply margins

Comment: images have some special treatment, because they are replaced elements, however the rule still stands that inline-elements can't be applied margin to.

Answer (score 0):

```
s += '&nbsp;<img alt="PLAY" src="' + imageDir + 'radio-play.gif" width="72" border="0" padding="5" height="61" style="cursor:pointer; cursor:hand" onclick="HandleAction(\'playnow\')">';
```

OR, more correctly,

```
s += '&nbsp;<img alt="PLAY" src="' + imageDir + 'radio-play.gif" width="72" border="0" padding="5" height="61" style="cursor:pointer; margin-left:5px;" onclick="HandleAction(\'playnow\')">';
```

Answer (score 0):

If "space" means visually rendered space to the left of the rendered button element, this would typically be done with CSS. A common implementation would be that the image tag itself, or a container of the image tag, has a CSS class attribute that assigns space appropriately. For the CSS to do this, look into things like padding, margins, absolute vs relative positioning, the `left` or `right` attributes, etc.